# Ripple effect of preference switch on SwitchMaterial?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

The switches in `PreferenceScreen` have nice ripple effects that go over the complete width. How can I get this ripple effect on a `SwitchMaterial` switch that is outside of a `PreferenceScreen` (in a normal layout)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touches on the *ViewGroup* whether directly on the *ViewGroup* or a child flow from the *ViewGroup* to the child and back down. I find [this post](https://suragch.medium.com/how-touch-events-are-delivered-in-android-eee3b607b038) and its associated Stack Overflow answer helpful in understanding touch events.

To get the *PreferenceScreen* ripple effect, set up the layout with the parent layout of the switch as clickable and focusable with a ripple background.

We will want the same response whether the switch or the *ViewGroup* is directly touched. The switch has its own responsive background, so the background of the switch is set to `@null` so it is not highlighted on touch events. This can be removed if the highlighting is desired.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/switchLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Since the switch will not receive click events because the parent is capturing them, we must programmatically click the switch when the *ViewGroup* is clicked:

```
val switchLayout = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.switchLayout)
switchLayout.setOnClickListener {
    findViewById<View>(R.id.switchWidget).performClick()
}
```

This all will give us the following:

[image]

Comment: besides the working effect I learned much from your explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```